# Dart: structuring assets

Tags: dart, assets, dart-pub, project-structure

I just read Dart's article on [Assets and Transformers](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/assets-and-transformers.html) and want to make sure I am understanding the correct way of structuring your `asset` directory.

Say my project name is `MyApp`, and it should produce - after cross-compiling - a JavaScript file called `myapp.dart.js`. Here is how I have the `asset` directory set up:

```
MyProject/
    asset/
        bootstrap/
            css/
                ...
            fonts/
                ...
            js/
                ...
        myapp/
            ... myapp's CSS and images
        ...other package's assets
    web/
        ...
```

Am I doing this right? Or should I be placing my assets some place else, or in a different convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's fine this way.

The asset directory is currently only supported by `pub serve` and `pub build` but not by the web server integrated into the Darteditor.